# How to run socket on wamp and which port to use for localhost

Tags: php, node.js, sockets

I am using *node.js* first time in my project and i am running my project on WAMP.

I have created *app.js* and code for my *app.js* is :

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var qs = require("querystring");

// Create an HTTP server for *socket.io* to listen on

var app = http.createServer();
var io = require("socket.io").listen(app);app.listen(8080);

var authorisedIPs = [
'127.0.0.1',
'192.168.0.204'
];

var clients = {};

function handler(req, res){

var remoteAddress = req.socket.remoteAddress;

if(authorisedIPs.indexOf(remoteAddress) >= 0) {

try{

    if(req.method == 'GET'){

    var body = '';

    req.on('error',function(){
      res.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      res.end("Error");
    });

    req.on('data',function(data){

      body += data;

      if(body.length > 1e6){
        response.writeHead(413, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        req.connection.destroy();
      }
    });

    req.on('end',function(){
        var returned = JSON.parse(body);
        var client_name =   returned.admin_id+'_'+returned.user_id+'_'+returned.login_id;
        var channel = returned.channel;
        var event = returned.status;

   for(var keys in clients){
   if(keys == client_name){

   var socket_to_send = clients[keys];
   socket_to_send.emit(channel,body);
   }
  }

  if(typeof socket_to_send != 'undefined'){
  }
    });
  }

  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  res.end("ok");
}
catch(error){
  res.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  res.end("Error");
 }
 }
 else{
 res.writeHead(401, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
 res.end("Unauthorised");
}
}

function sendData(socket){
var thisRef = this;
var currentTimeObj = new Date();


var formattedTime = currentTimeObj.getDate() + "-" +currentTimeObj.getMonth() + "-" + currentTimeObj.getFullYear() + " " + currentTimeObj.getHours() + ":" + currentTimeObj.getMinutes() + ":" + currentTimeObj.getSeconds();
socket.emit('timeUpdate', { currentTime:  formattedTime});
setTimeout(function(){
sendData.call(thisRef,socket)
},1000);
  }

  function testfunc(socket){
  socket.emit('testEvent', { message: 'testing...'});
  }

 function testfunc1(socket){
 socket.emit('testEvent', { message: 'testing1...'});
 }

 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.emit('get_name', {});
socket.on('forceDisconnect',function(data12){
  for(var keysd in clients){
    if (keysd == data12.my_name) {
      delete clients[keysd];
      socket.disconnect();
    }
  }
});

socket.on('take_name', function (data11) {
    clients[data11.my_name] = socket;
});

   });

  function getsplitText(string,splitter,index){
  return_arr = string.split(splitter);
  return return_arr[index];
 }

  http.createServer(handler).listen(8080, '192.168.0.204');
```

and my client side html is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Server Time poller</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="statusMessageDiv">

</div>
<div id="serverTimeDiv"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script src="192.168.0.204:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
alert('hello');
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.204:8080');

socket.on('testEvent',function(data){
$("#statusMessageDiv").html(data.welcomeMessage);
socket.emit('testRevert',{message:'acknowledged'});
 });
socket.on('timeUpdate', function (data) {
$("#serverTimeDiv").html(data.currentTime);
});
});
</script>
</html>
```

When I run *app.js* on console,I get the response

```
info - socket.io started.
```

But when I open *index.html* in my browser,I get the alert 'hello' and then error

```
ReferenceError: io is not defined
 var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.204:8080');
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing it properly I think the issue is with your ports:

You use port 3000 here:
`<script src="192.168.0.204:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

and your app runs on port `8080`

Comment: How about the ports? You are using once port 3000 and the other time port 8080